# iteration in object variables swift

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

basically, i have this decodable model from server

```
class CalculateModel: Decodable {
    var ipn     : CalculateModelDetail?
    var sn      : CalculateModelDetail?
    var opv     : CalculateModelDetail?
    var oppv    : CalculateModelDetail?
    var opvr    : CalculateModelDetail?
    var so      : CalculateModelDetail?
    var osms    : CalculateModelDetail?
    var vosms   : CalculateModelDetail?
}
class CalculateModelDetail : Decodable {
    var value   : Double?
    var name    : String?
    var payer   : String?
}
```

What i want to do is something like this

```
var calculatedValue: CalculateModel?

*api logic*
{
self.calculatedValue = result
}
```

how do i iterate those values?

```
for element in calculatedValue {
print(element)

}
```

has to print ipn, sn, opv
like that, but it's not logically correct ofc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to decode it like this and remove `CalculateModel`

```
let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:CalculateModelDetail].self,from:data)
```

By this you have more control over the keys and values

```
print(Array(res.keys))
print(Array(res.values))
```

Comment: i just want use it in for loop

Comment: `calculatedValue ` isn't an array you can't interate over it you should use dot operator to access it's properties like `calculatedValue.ipn`